# How can I convert my onclick JS into a click event listener?

Tags: javascript

Here is my codepen showing the onclick and javascript code. I'm trying to convert the JS into addEventListener, but I can't get it to work

https://codepen.io/designextras/pen/NWxaowR

```
const menuIcon = document.querySelector('#menu-bars')
const sideMenu = document.querySelector('#nav-menu')



function showMenu() {
if(true) {
    sideMenu.classList.add('active')
}
}

function hideMenu() {
if(true) {
    sideMenu.classList.remove('active')
}
}
```

HTML

```
  <div id="navbar">
        <a href="#" id="menu-bars" onclick="showMenu()">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
    </div>

    <nav id="nav-menu">
        <ul class="nav-menu-items">
            <div id="navbar-toggle">
                <a href="#" id="menu-bars" onclick="hideMenu()">
                    <i class="fas fa-bars nav-icon"></i> 
                </a>
```

Comment: I do not see any attempts to use `.addEventListener`. Could you please update the code with that?

Comment: Opening menu is straight forward. Closing it is the tricky part. You will have multiple menu items. So you will have to use `querySelectorAll` and then loop on all elements and add listener individually.

Comment: could you edit the codepen and add how you'd do that? because I figured out how to open it with addeventlisten, but the closing part is what I'm stuck on

Comment: @Brian, Could you please accept the solution if it resolves your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `onClick` and include `addEventListener` like,

```
menuIcon.addEventListener('click', showMenu);
hideMenuIcon.addEventListener('click', hideMenu);
```

`id` should be unique but you are using it in two places `id="menu-bars"` which you can modify as like below snippet..

I have included new `id` for closing one and selected element like,

```
const hideMenuIcon = document.querySelector('#hide-menu-bars')
```

https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/ZEQXwvv

And snippet as follows,

```js
const menuIcon = document.querySelector('#menu-bars')
const hideMenuIcon = document.querySelector('#hide-menu-bars')
const sideMenu = document.querySelector('#nav-menu')



function showMenu() {
    if(true) {
        sideMenu.classList.add('active')
    }
}

function hideMenu() {
    if(true) {
        sideMenu.classList.remove('active')
    }
} 

menuIcon.addEventListener('click', showMenu);
hideMenuIcon.addEventListener('click', hideMenu);
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#navbar {
    background-color: #212121;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: start;
    align-items: center;
}

#menu-bars {
    margin-left: 2rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: #fff;
} 

#hide-menu-bars {
    margin-left: 2rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: #fff;
} 

#nav-menu {
    background: #212121;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    transition: 450ms;
}

#nav-menu.active {
    left: 0;
    transition: 450ms;
}

.nav-text {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: start;
    list-style: none;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-xxzQGERXS00kBmZW/6qxqJPyxW3UR0BPsL4c8ILaIWXva5kFi7TxkIIaMiKtqV1Q" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
</head>
<div id="navbar">
            <a href="#" id="menu-bars">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    
        <nav id="nav-menu">
            <ul class="nav-menu-items">
                <div id="navbar-toggle">
                    <a href="#" id="hide-menu-bars">
                        <i class="fas fa-bars nav-icon"></i> 
                    </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to find the `id`s and add event listeners to that. Something like this:

```js
const menuIcon = document.querySelector('#menu-bars')
const sideMenu = document.querySelector('#nav-menu')


menuIcon.addEventListener('click', function(){
   sideMenu.classList.add('active')
})

sideMenu.addEventListener('click', function(){
 sideMenu.classList.remove('active')
})
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#navbar {
    background-color: #212121;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: start;
    align-items: center;
}

#menu-bars {
    margin-left: 2rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: #fff;
} 

#nav-menu {
    background: #212121;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    transition: 450ms;
}

#nav-menu.active {
    left: 0;
    transition: 450ms;
}

.nav-text {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: start;
    list-style: none;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-xxzQGERXS00kBmZW/6qxqJPyxW3UR0BPsL4c8ILaIWXva5kFi7TxkIIaMiKtqV1Q" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
</head>
<div id="navbar">
            <a href="#" id="menu-bars">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    
        <nav id="nav-menu">
            <ul class="nav-menu-items">
                <div id="navbar-toggle">
                    <a href="#" id="menu-bars">
                        <i class="fas fa-bars nav-icon"></i> 
                    </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

As commented,

> Opening menu is straight forward. Closing it is the tricky part. You will have multiple menu items. So you will have to use querySelectorAll and then loop on all elements and add listener individually.

#### Idea

- You will have multiple menu items. So you cannot use `ids` to fetch. For this you can use following pattern: `#nav-menu a`
- Now fetvhing them would mean you will get a NodeList instead of HTMLElement.
- So you will have to loop over the list and assign listener to indivudual elements.

Following is a sample:

```js
const menuIcon = document.querySelector('#navbar a');
const menuItems = document.querySelector('#nav-menu a');
const sideMenu = document.querySelector('#nav-menu')

menuIcon.addEventListener('click', showMenu);
menuItems.addEventListener('click', hideMenu);

function showMenu() {
    if(true) {
        sideMenu.classList.add('active')
    }
}

function hideMenu() {
    if(true) {
        sideMenu.classList.remove('active')
    }
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#navbar {
    background-color: #212121;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: start;
    align-items: center;
}

#menu-bars {
    margin-left: 2rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: #fff;
} 

#nav-menu {
    background: #212121;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    transition: 450ms;
}

#nav-menu.active {
    left: 0;
    transition: 450ms;
}

.nav-text {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: start;
    list-style: none;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-xxzQGERXS00kBmZW/6qxqJPyxW3UR0BPsL4c8ILaIWXva5kFi7TxkIIaMiKtqV1Q" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
</head>
<div id="navbar">
            <a href="#" id="menu-bars">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    
        <nav id="nav-menu">
            <ul class="nav-menu-items">
                <div id="navbar-toggle">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-bars nav-icon"></i> 
                    </a>
```

Comment: ```id="menu-bars"``` should be unique.. Already you have added ```addEventListener``` in JS then you also have ```onclick``` in HTML template..

Comment: But that is what OP needs.. He wants to convert HTML ```onClick``` to JS ```addEventListener``` .. So it needs to be removed from markup..

Comment: @ManirajMurugan Yup. Forgot to remove `onClick`. Have updated my answer. Please check